# Integral of polynomial using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have an integral problem that I'm working on, it's a polynomial which I imagine either can't be factored or needs to be completed, and then substituted using a trig identity:

$$\int{\frac{10x^2+4x+2}{(1+4x^2)(x+2)}}\,\,dx$$

If someone could give me a hint at how to start tackling this problem, I'd really appreciate it - just need a jumping off point as I feel a bit stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Using partial fractions

$$\frac{10x^2+4x+2}{(1+4x^2)(x+2)}=\frac{Ax+B}{1+4x^2}+\frac{C}{x+2}$$

And by the way, this is not a polynomial. It is a rational function.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate the input!